# Razor giving me blank spaces when setting value in HTML

Tags: razor

Hi I have the following HTML Input:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="DisableNotification"  @{ if (Model.DisableNotification == true) { <text>checked="checked"</text> }} value="@{ if (Model.DisableNotification == true) { <text>1</text> } else{ <text>0</text>}}">
```

This works fine but is adding blank spaces when I see the value in the Chrome debugger:

[image]

If you see there is blank space before the 1 value and after.  Any clue why is doing that?

Comment: Try { <text>1</text> } to {<text>1</text>} remove the space before and after the text tags

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you want to write that as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space before and after the text tags